# Differences between ListDirectory and ListDirectoryDetails FTP methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to list the files in FT Pserver.

I use `ListDirectory` and `ListDirectoryDetails` FTP methods for listing the files.

That get the files list, but the count of files in `ListDirectory` is less than `ListDirectoryDetails` method, but I don't know why?

Is it possible???

Answer (score 1):

The `ListDirectory` method uses FTP `NLST` command.

The `ListDirectoryDetails` method uses FTP `LIST` command.

It's up to the FTP server, what it returns in a response to each of the commands. The .NET framework does not control it anyhow.

The [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) says only this:

- `LIST`:
  The RFC says nothing about what the list should contains, just that:

  > Since the information on a file may vary widely from system
  > to system, this information may be hard to use automatically
  > in a program, but may be quite useful to a human user.
- `NLST`:

  > The server
  > will return a stream of names of files and no other
  > information.

We do not know what you FTP server is, so we cannot give you more details.